# How can Locks and Atomics able to limit data structure size in C++?

Tags: c++, optimization, locking, constants, atomic

I was given this code on sequential, lock, and atomic programming. I think I’m starting to understand the code as a whole; however, I don’t understand how/if it changes the max size of a circular buffer. I’m not sure if I don’t understand the code but I’m almost certain that “size_”, is an unchangeable constant. This seems like a trick question.

Is it possible for Locks and Atomics to change a constant data structure size?

If a seq_buffer is made with size_ == 100, how many elements can be stored?

- This should obviously be 100. My intuition tells me that if you create something with size 100, it’s max size will be 100

If a locked_buffer is created with size_ == 100, how many elements can be stored at maximum?

- Keyword Mutable allows more flexibility on constants; however, I don’t think it’s used on size, so I would assume all 100 elements can be stored. I
  can’t imagine a case where this is false.

If an atomic_buffer is created with size_ == 100, How many elements can be stored, as maximum?

- Using atomics would involving having a global buffer that threads can
  store and access elements from, thus the maximum size would be
  globally 100 for all the threads to share. I’m assuming the max
  elements storage for this is 100, again.

Thank you for reading, any help would be appreciated!

Here is the code:

Locked Buffer:

```
#ifndef LOCKEDBUFFER_H
#define LOCKEDBUFFER_H

#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <atomic>

#include "optional.h"

template <typename T>
class locked_buffer {
public:
  // Creates buffer of size n
  locked_buffer(int n) :
    size_{n},
    buf_{new optional<T>[size_]}
  {
  }

  // Remove copy constructor
  locked_buffer(const locked_buffer &) = delete;

  // Destructor (default generated)
  ~locked_buffer() = default;

  // Gets buffer size
  int size() const noexcept {
    return size_;
  }

  // Checks if buffer is empty
  bool empty() const noexcept {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l{mut_};
    return is_empty();
  }

  // Checks if buffer is full
  bool full() const noexcept {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l{mut_};
    return is_full();
  }

  // Put an optional value in the queue
  void put(const optional<T> & x);

  // Get a value from the queue
  optional<T> get();

private:
  // Next circular position to position p
  int next_position(int p) const noexcept {
    return p + ((p+1>=size_)?(1-size_):1);
  }

  // Check if buffer is empty without locking
  bool is_empty() const noexcept {
    return (next_read_ == next_write_);
  }

  // Check if buffer is full without locking
  bool is_full() const noexcept {
    const int next = next_position(next_write_);
    return next == next_read_;
  }

private:
  const int size_;
  const std::unique_ptr<optional<T>[]> buf_;
  int next_read_ = 0;
  int next_write_ = 0;

  mutable std::mutex mut_;
  std::condition_variable not_full_;
  std::condition_variable not_empty_;
};


template <typename T>
void locked_buffer<T>::put(const optional<T> & x) 
{
  using namespace std;
  unique_lock<mutex> l{mut_};
  not_full_.wait(l, [this] { return !is_full(); });
  buf_[next_write_] = x;
  next_write_ = next_position(next_write_);
  not_empty_.notify_one();
}

template <typename T>
optional<T> locked_buffer<T>::get()
{
  using namespace std;
  unique_lock<mutex> l{mut_};
  not_empty_.wait(l, [this] { return !is_empty(); });
  auto res = buf_[next_read_];
  next_read_ = next_position(next_read_);
  not_full_.notify_one();
  return res;
}

#endif
```

Atomic Buffer:

```
#ifndef ATOMICBUFFER_H
#define ATOMICBUFFER_H

#include <memory>
#include <atomic>
#include <utility>

#include "optional.h"

template <typename T>
class atomic_buffer {
public:
  // Creates buffer of size n
  atomic_buffer(int n) :
    size_{n},
    buf_{new optional<T>[size_]}
  {
  }

  // Destructor (default generated)
  ~atomic_buffer() = default;

  // Gets buffer size
  int size() const noexcept {
    return size_;
  }

  // Check whether buffer is empty
  bool empty() const noexcept {
    return next_read_ == next_write_;
  }

  // Check whether buffer is full
  bool full() const noexcept {
    const int next = next_position(next_write_.load());
    return next == next_read_.load();
  }

  // Put an optional value in the queue
  void put(const optional<T> & x);

  // Get an optional value from the queue
  optional<T> get();

private:
  int next_position(int p) const noexcept {
    return p + ((p+1>=size_)?(1-size_):1);
  }

private:
  const int size_;
  const std::unique_ptr<optional<T>[]> buf_;
  alignas(64) std::atomic<int> next_read_ {0};
  alignas(64) std::atomic<int> next_write_ {0};
};

template <typename T>
void atomic_buffer<T>::put(const optional<T> & x) 
{
  const int next = next_position(next_write_.load());
  while (next == next_read_.load()) {
    ;
  }
  buf_[next_write_.load()] = x;
  next_write_.store(next);
}

template <typename T>
optional<T> atomic_buffer<T>::get()
{
  while (empty()) {
    ;
  }
  auto res = buf_[next_read_.load()];
  next_read_.store(next_position(next_read_.load()));
  return res;
}

#endif
```

Comment: Atomics can only work with datatypes your CPU can handle with a single instruction.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Both your classes initialize their storage as `new optional<T>[size_]`, so you can store `size_` `optional<T>`s in either of them.  Also, it doesn't look like `atomic_buffer`'s synchronization is actually sufficient.